# Delete files in ftp name containing a string

Tags: php

I would like to delete in a FTP folder (and subfolders) all files that contain "2019" string in the name

For example 201902_QSA4_CA.pdf  => This file will be deleted

Here my code, but not run:

```
$web = 'mipage.com';
$user = 'xxxx';
$pass = 'xxxx';
//connect
$conn_id = ftp_connect($web);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$user,$pass);

$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("pdfs/archivo/");
$display = Array ('2019');
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file)
{
    if (in_array(reset(explode('.', $file)), $display))
        unlink($file);
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Someone can help me?

Thxs

Regards

Comment: You are not actually reading anything via the FTP connection to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

[ftp_nlist](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) will allow you to use a wildcard to get file list.

```
$web = 'mipage.com';
$user = 'xxxx';
$pass = 'xxxx';
//connect
$conn_id = ftp_connect($web);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$user,$pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/pdfs/archivo/2019*");

foreach ($files as $file_name)
{
    ftp_delete($conn_id, $file_name);
}
```

If you need to find subdirectories recursively, you can do it like this.

```
$web = 'mipage.com';
$user = 'xxxx';
$pass = 'xxxx';
//connect
$conn_id = ftp_connect($web);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$user,$pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$files = [];
$ftpRecursiveSearcher = function ($path, $pattern) use (&$ftpRecursiveSearcher, &$files, &$conn_id)
        {
            $list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path);
            foreach ($list as $name)
            {
                if (ftp_size($conn_id, $name) === -1)
                {
                    $ftpRecursiveSearcher($name, $pattern);
                    $targets = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "{$name}/{$pattern}");
                    $files = array_merge($files, $targets);
                }
            }
        };

$ftpRecursiveSearcher('pdfs/archivo', '2019*'); // 'pdfs/archivo' is relative path

array_walk($files, function ($file) use (&$conn_id) {
            ftp_delete($conn_id, $file); 
        });
```